# When deserializing Protobuf in C#, how do I introduce the correct protobuf type?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I use the proto file [dm.proto](https://github.com/SocialSisterYi/bilibili-API-collect/blob/master/grpc_api/bilibili/community/service/dm/v1/dm.proto) in this project to input the official compiler [protoc-21.12-win64](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v21.12/protoc-21.12-win64.zip) to generate the parsing file [Dm.cs](https://github.com/SocialSisterYi/bilibili-API-collect/files/10720437/Dm.zip)

The data I need to parse is a file: [seg.so](https://api.bilibili.com/x/v2/dm/web/seg.so?type=1&oid=1176840&pid=810872&segment_index=1)

[Code is from here](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/csharptutorial/)

How to modify the official code to parse this file? I want to parse this file into json, should I use the official code?

```
Person john;
using (var input = File.OpenRead("john.dat"))
{
    john = Person.Parser.ParseFrom(input);
}
```

Comment: What content you get in `response.Content`?

Comment: It would help if you could give more precise information than "but I have not been able to get it done" as well. I would suggest separating out the HTTP part entirely - load a file from disk (you can save the content of a previous HTTP response for example). That way you should be able to provide a [mcve] with details of the compile-time errors or exceptions you receive.

Comment: Did you read the tutorial from ms? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-the-grpc-client-in-a-net-console-app-1

Comment: @Chetan In the above code, ```response.Content``` returns ```System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent```. If the code is changed to string response = client.GetStringAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();, the value of response is ```Y�����ڏ��� (���260e09991:一条弹幕@��ݗHb1118087686683729920p���0�0
Y�����܏�ь (���260e09991:两条弹幕@��ݗHb1118087751233980416p���0�0"?��```

Comment: Since you tagged protobuf .net, you might want to read [Working with .proto files with protobuf-net and protobuf-net.BuildTools](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/contract_first.html)

Comment: @JonSkeet That's a good idea, but the reason I didn't do it is, I'm not sure if the process of converting the "https response" to a "stream" will corrupt the protobuf data, which is in some non-string that I don't understand form exists.

My problem is that I don't know which protobuf function to combine with Dm.cs, and which of the hundreds of elements in Dm.cs?

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks, this didn't quite solve the problem, but it got me a step forward

Comment: `Stream` is binary data - unless *you* convert it to text, it should be fine. But fundamentally we don't know what your proto looks like, or which proto message you're trying to parse. `Person.Parser.ParseFrom(input)` should work if you're trying to deserialize a `Person` from data in `input` for example...

Comment: @JonSkeet I modified the question, it should be much clearer now :-) (in fact, if you open the WebAPI I gave in the Chrome, the Chrome will give you a file called "seg.so", which is what I want to parse)

Comment: "I want to parse this file into json" - do you mean you want to *reformat* it as JSON? I note that this is the first time you've mentioned this - until this point, it sounded like you *just* wanted to parse the file into an in-memory representation of the message. Does the code you've provided work so far, in terms of parsing to an in-memory representation? Your question is still very unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh my god, my apologies here... yes, I want to reformat "seg.so" as JSON. This code can't parse it into memory because I don't know how to use "Dm.cs" with this code. For example, "Person" in the original tutorial still appears with the original name "Person" after compilation, and there is a "ParseFrom()" function in the file, but this does not seem to be the case in the "Dm.cs" file I obtained through compilation. There are a lot of functions in there with names containing "From" and I don't know how to call it.

Comment: Well okay, you don't have a `Person` message - but what message *are* you trying to parse? All you need to do is change the code to `Avatar.Parser.ParseFrom` or whatever type is actually relevant - which you haven't told us about... (Once you've parsed, you can just call `ToString()` to get a JSON representation, unless you want any specific formatting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know which message you're trying to parse - the protobuf wire format doesn't include include any sort of schema indication. But once you know that, it should be simple:

```cs
// Change this to whichever message type you expect the data to be.
// Your proto file contains lots of messages... I'm guessing at the one
// you wanted, based on the service and the filename.
DmSegOttReply reply = DmSegOttReply.Parser.ParseFrom(data);

// If you need different formatting options you can use JsonFormatter,
// but normally ToString is all you need.
string json = avatar.ToString();
```

Comment: You killed my question! (complimentary sense
) I understood the structure of this file from the code you gave, and finally, I filled ```DmSegMobileReply``` into the code you gave and got a perfect json parsing result. (The choice of ```DmSegMobileReply``` comes from the place where dm.proto is customized), thank you.